# Conserving variance of normally disributed vector in linear transformation

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, neural-networks

I have normally distibuted vector $X$ with known variance $Var(X)$ and mean $\overline X$ and then I take new vector $Y$ as $W*X$ where $W$ is normally distributed matrix. If I required $Y$ to have same variance and mean as $X$, what should $Var(W)$ and $\overline W$ be ? More generally - given $\overline X$, $Var(X)$, $\overline W$ and $Var(W)$, what would $\overline {W*X}$ and $Var(W*X)$ be ?

Note : For the desired application ( initialization in neural networks), the equality of means isn't really necessary as both means are likely to be almost zero anyway

Comment: Could you be clearer about the distribution assumptions? Since $X$ is a vector, is $\text{Var}(X)$ the covariance matrix, or are you saying that the components of $X$ are i.i.d with common variance? Is $W$ independent of $X$? etc.

Comment: By $Var(X)$ i mean common variance. $X$ and $W$ are independent on each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So $X$ has i.i.d. normal entries, and $W$ has i.i.d. normal entries.

The entries of $WX$ will **not** be normal.

But you can answer your question about means and variances without any normality assumptions on $W$ and $X$.

Let $W$ have dimension $m \times n$.

Since $$Y_i = \sum_{j=1}^n W_{i,j} X_j$$
we can use independence to obtain
$$E[Y_i] = \sum_{j=1}^n E[W_{i,j}] E[X_j] =  n \overline{W} \overline{X}$$
and
$$\text{Var}(Y_i) = \sum_{j=1}^n \text{Var}(W_{i,j} X_j) = n[
\text{Var}(X) \text{Var}(W) + \text{Var}(X) \overline{W}^2 + \text{Var}(W) \overline{X}^2
].$$

Setting these equal to $\overline{X}$ and $\text{Var}(X)$ respectively yields $\overline{W} = 1/n$ and $$\text{Var}(W) = \frac{\left(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n^2}\right)\text{Var}(X)}{\text{Var}(X) + \overline{X}^2}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, thats exactly what i was looking for.